# Is it possible to clear cache in Databricks Notebook?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Is it possible to clear the cache in Azure Databricks Notebook? I converted a column from string to date and I see it was really converted from the job run, like so:

```py
df.withColumn('Date', F.to_date('Date', 'yyyyMMdd'))
Out[167]: DataFrame[bla bla bla, Date: date]
```

But when I check the dataframe schema, I am still seeing string

Comment: which databricks are you using? azure or aws?

Comment: have you looked here? [CLEAR CACHE](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-cache-clear-cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the kernel and you should be good to go.

Comment: Detach and reattach will clear all variables w/o restarting

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you just need to assign your transformation.

```py
df = df.withColumn('Date', F.to_date('Date', 'yyyyMMdd'))
```

Any transformation you make on dataframe are not "inplace". They return a new dataframe that you need to assign to a variable to save the transformation.